How to keep history trend in Allure Report?
I use Maven for building project: lets say to run test U use mvn clean test; Then I have maven-allure plugin and I generate report once tests completed. I know that to keep history I have to place history folder to allure-results every time but how to do it automatically e.g. by default report results goes to target/ folder and every time I run tests again that is cleared.
